# Precise definition of "weaker" and "stronger"?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

If I say that $A$ is stronger than $B$, do I mean that $A \Rightarrow B$, or that $B \Rightarrow A$?  (Or something else?)

I feel like I have seen both usages in literature, which is confusing.

Thoughts based on intuition:

$A \Rightarrow B$ means $A$ is a special case of $B$ -- $B$ is more general. This would seem to imply that $B$ is "stronger". (Example: $n$ is an integer implies $n$ is a real number.)

$A \Rightarrow B$ also means that whenever $A$ holds, $B$ must hold. This would seem to imply that $A$ is "stronger".

Comment: A stronger **theorem** is one which has a weaker hypothesis and/or a stronger conclusion.

Comment: In your example "n is an integer implies n is a real number", you are thinking of the predicates involved. The integers are a proper subset of the real numbers. That might be the source of your confusion. When logicians talk about A being stronger than B, they're talking about A and B as distinct statements without regard to the predicates they contain, as Asaf explains.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. So when I say "A is stronger than B", precisely what can A and B be? Only theorems? Logical sentences?

Comment: @bo1024: It means $A$ implies more sentences, then $B$. This is equivalent to $A \Rightarrow B$ because $\Rightarrow$ is a preorder.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If $A\Rightarrow B$, then for every $C$, if $B\Rightarrow C$ we have that $A\Rightarrow C$.
Therefore $A$ implies *at least* the same propositions that $B$ implies.

We have two options from here:

1. $B\Rightarrow A$, in which case $A$ is **equivalent** to $B$, and they imply the same things.
2. $B\nRightarrow A)$, that is $B$ does *not* imply $A$. We have if so that $A$ is *stronger* than $B$ since $A\implies A$, but $B$ does not.

In essence "$A$ is *stronger* than $B$" is when $\{C\mid B\Rightarrow C\}\subsetneq\{C\mid A\Rightarrow C\}$, and *equivalent* is when the sets are equal.

Comment: I am being somewhat inaccurate for didactic reasons, and I am not mentioning any underlying theory which may be required for some of the implications.

Comment: Could you add an example or two?

Comment: Take the language of equality. The empty theory is weaker than the theory stating that there are at least two different elements.

Comment: What's your reference?

Comment: @R.W.Prado: For what?

Comment: What's your reference for the definition for the definition of **stronger**? Where can I find a definition for it?  For me, it sounds more natural to say **strictly stronger** when speaking about your sense of **stronger**. I use A **stronger** than B when $A \implies B$ .

Comment: I don't have a reference, just world experience, I suppose. Do you think that a 5kg ball is heavier than a 5kg brick?

Comment: It sounds weird to say it in that context, but yeah... I could to say that 5kg ball is heavier than a 5kg brick, but I would prefer to say that 5kg ball is equivalent to a 5kg brick.

Answer (score 20):

Let's make the simplifying assumption that $\lnot(B \implies A)$.

Then $A \implies B$ can be informally expressed as "$A$ is (strictly) stronger than $B$."

It is certainly possible that in this situation, at some time, someone has instead written "$B$ is stronger than $A$."  Stuff happens.  We all have written $x<y$ when we meant $y<x$.  And interchange of "necessary condition" and "sufficient condition" happens so (relatively) often that it may be best to avoid these terms.

But "$A$ is stronger than $B$" has only one correct interpretation in terms of the direction of the implication (with disagreement, possibly, in the case of equivalence.)

**However**, suppose that we have proved theorem $X$, $\:$(a) under the assumption $A$, and $\:$(b) under the assumption $B$.  Then the result (b) is considered to be a **stronger** result than the result (a). That is perfectly consistent with the ordinary meaning of "stronger," since
$$(B \implies X) \implies (A\implies X).$$

Comment: What's your reference? I usually see the term “strictly stronger”, but not stronger.