# What does it signify that a mathematical condition is weaker than the other mathematical condition?

Tags: terminology, definition

I will begin with the definitions of **Restricted Isometry Property (RIP)** and
**Robust Null Space Property (RNSP)**, which are the two widely used sufficient conditions for robust sparse recovery in the field of compressed sensing.

Definition 1:
A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is said to satisfy the **restricted
isometry property (RIP)** of order $k$ with constant $\delta_k \in (0,1)$ if
$$
(1 - \delta_k) ||u||_2^2 \leq || Au||_2^2\leq (1 + \delta_k) ||u||_2^2 ,\forall u\  \mbox{such that}\  ||u||_0\leq k.
$$

Definition 2: A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is said to satisfy the **robust null space property
(RNSP)** of order $k$ with constants $\rho \in (0,1)$
and $\tau \in \mathbb{R}_+$, if for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $S \subset \{1,\ 2,...,\ n\}$
with $|S| \leq k$, it is true that
$$
||h_S||_1 \leq \rho ||h_{S^c} ||_1 +  ||Ah||_2 .
$$

Now, I present the theorem which connects the **RIP** to the **RNSP**.

Theorem 1 : Suppose that, for some number $t > 1$, the matrix $A$ satisfies the RIP of
order $tk$ with constant $\delta_{tk} =: \delta < \sqrt{ (t-1)/t }$.
Define
$$
\nu := \sqrt{t(t-1)} - (t-1) \in (0,0.5) ,
$$
$$
a := [ \nu ( 1 - \nu) - \delta ( 0.5 - \nu + \nu^2) ]^{1/2},
$$
$$
b := \nu ( 1 - \nu ) \sqrt{1+\delta} ,
c := \left[ \frac { \delta \nu^2 }{ 2(t-1) } \right]^{1/2} .
$$
Then $A$ satisfies the RNSP with constants.
$$
\rho = \frac{c}{a} < 1 ,\  \tau = \frac{b \sqrt{k} }{a^2}.
$$
Based on the above theorem, the author says:
$$\textbf{RIP}\implies \textbf{RNSP}$$
And hence, **RNSP** is a weaker sufficient condition
than the **RIP**.

**Now, I understand how RIP implies RNSP. But I don't understand what the significance of the
statement that RNSP is a weaker sufficient condition. What does it signify that RNSP is a weaker sufficient condition than the RIP ?
Does it mean RNSP is a less restrictive condition than the RIP?**

Comment: To say that "P is a [sufficient condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) for Q" means that "if P, then Q" holds. Thus, the first statement in your post means that both RIP and RNSP are suff condition for "robust sparse recovery" property,

Comment: And see [Precise definition of "weaker" and "stronger"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53708/precise-definition-of-weaker-and-stronger)

Comment: So we have RIP to RSNP to robust sparse recovery. And RIP is stronger because it implies RNSP.

Comment: If you are a dog then you are a mammal.  Knowing that you are a mammal only does not give much information on whether or not you are a dog, hence being a mammal is a weaker condition.